# delete all but one line based on several identifiers

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one table TPAIE, 2 pieces of information:

- numben (number of the beneficiary)
- datPai (date when I pay the guy)

Normally for one date, I must have one beneficiary (I pay the guy once for a date). Nevertheless it happens that I have several lines with the same beneficiary and the same date

```
    COUNTING NUMBEN   PERPAI 

     9 75005100 01/08/13 
     9 75005109 01/08/13
```

How could I delete all of the lines but one for each of these beneficiairy and for a specific date?

**Note:** I found something like that but it works if I have only one identifier

```
delete from tpaie where numben not in 
(select min(numben) from tpaie group by numben, perpai);
```

Note 2 : I found this sql which could delete all lines that exist several times : I just to say 'dont delete the first one). A rownum somewhere ?

```
delete from tpaie a 
where (numben, perpai) in (
select numben, perpai from tpaie b where b.rowid <> a.rowid)
```

Comment: "delete all of the lines but one". Which one do you not want to delete?

Comment: In your example `COUNTING` is the same but `NUMBEN` is different, is that intentional?

Comment: @Dour High : anyone, they are the same

Comment: @Goat : no, it is just a part of it : just to show that for example I have 9 lines for 75005100 the first of august

Comment: Sorry but i do not understand what you want, can you post a data example, one table with data source and other with final data?. I have confused between first and second query that you posted, i can't find a pattern. I know how add a rowid for each one, but first I must understand a little more. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your second try you are near from the goal. You just need to understand that `rowid` is reserved word for unique physical table row identifier. Check [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm) to find out more.

Query:

```
delete tpaie 
where rowid not in (
  select distinct
    ( first_value(rowid) over (
        partition by numben, perpai order by rowid
      )
    ) first_row_id
  from 
    tpaie
)
```

You can see complete test in [this SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dc56e/11).

**Update**
@mlwacosmos has found a variant with better performance. Of course, `not in` in original answer isn`t a good practice. So I added his variant to answer too for future reference:

```
delete from tpaie a 
where 
  rowid not in ( 
    select distinct 
      ( first_value(rowid) 
          over (partition by numben, perpai order by rowid) 
      ) first_row_id 
    from 
      tpaie b 
    where 
      a.numben = b.numben 
      and 
      a.perpai = b.perpai 
  ) 
  and 
  (numben, perpai) in ( select numben, perpai 
                        from tpaie b 
                        where b.rowid <> a.rowid 
                      )
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dc56e/13)

But this solution involves `not in` again, so may be better to use `in` function with another analytic ranking:

```
delete from tpaie a 
where 
  rowid in ( 
    select row_id 
    from (
      select 
        rowid row_id, 
        ( dense_rank() over ( -- enumerate rows
            partition by numben, perpai order by rowid
          )
        ) row_rank
      from 
        tpaie
    )  
    where
      row_rank > 1 -- eliminate rows ranked first
  )
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dc56e/19)

Comment: +1, Great!, for the query and the example in SQLFiddle, I did not know of: `FOR var IN 1 .. x LOOP`, `ROWID`, `ROWIDTOCHAR` and `first_value`. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I can not set this answer as accepted because I did not question. Also your answer was helpful for me to solve other problem.

Comment: @GastonF. Sorry, I just mistook you and original poster. I'm hope that you forgive me this mistake. But, by the way, I learned `ROWIDTOCHAR` nearly at the same time as you because never  before deal with JDBC output like [that SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dc56e/12). All client applications, which I used before, just output `rowid` values as strings. So, it's possible to learn while answering  a questions too. :)

Comment: very interesting but very slow too... is there a way to use EXISTS?

Comment: Because of your answer I could find the right request and it goes fast this time : delete from tpaie a
where rowid not in (
  select distinct
    ( first_value(rowid) over (
        partition by numben, perpai order by rowid
      )
    ) first_row_id
  from 
    tpaie b where a.numben = b.numben and a.perpai = b.perpai
) and (numben, perpai) in (
select numben, perpai from tpaie b where b.rowid <> a.rowid 
)

Comment: @mlwacosmos I update answer and add new variant of query. May be it executes faster, but I can't test it with big amount of data, so you can test it if you need ...

Comment: @thinkjet I confirm the rapidity of the last request... I am not 100% sure but indeed it seems to be faster than the one I proposed

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporay table with DISTINCT to get only one entry per ben, per date, delele all entries in your main table and reload it with the temp table, something like :

```
SELECT DISTINCT numben, perpai 
INTO #temp
FROM tpaie

DELETE FROM tpaie

INSERT INTO tpaie
SELECT * FROM #temp
```

EDIT :

For a specific date, try :

```
SELECT DISTINCT numben, perpai 
INTO #temp
FROM tpaie
WHERE perpai = '01/08/13'

DELETE FROM tpaie
WHERE perpai = '01/08/13'

INSERT INTO tpaie
SELECT * FROM #temp
```